# How do you do Krieg the Psycho's invincibility glitch?

Tags: borderlands-2

There's a glitch where Krieg the Psycho can become invincible. How do you do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must have two things to perform Krieg the Psycho's invincibility glitch:

1. the [Release the Beast](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Release_the_Beast) major game-changer, tier 6 skill at the bottom of the [Mania](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Mania) (middle) skill-branch, and
2. a vehicle that you can teleport to via Catch-A-Ride station.

When your health is at or below 33%, activate your action skill (Buzz Axe Rampage) to transform into a Badass Psycho Mutant. Teleport to a vehicle as you start. Thenceforth, you are invincible. Not even your vehicle can take damage. If you travel to another area, it cancels the invincibility. Respawning also cancels invincibility.

Being hit by a(n enemy) vehicle while-on-foot can still instantly cripple you (and kill you if you are already crippled). [Orphan Maker](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Orphan_Maker)'s Curse of the Nefarious Backlash! does not cause damage to you. You cannot hit yourself with your own rockets.